# NextJS: How to use SSG with multilingual?

Tags: next.js, multilingual

Currently I'm using SSG which is perfect. But I want my site support multilingual. I tried next-18next but it doesn't support SSG now.

I'm thinking using local subpath (e.g domain.com and domain.com/es) but I cannot imagine how to generate a new set of static html pages of the new language.

Does anyone have any idea?